# jquery button not executing

Tags: php, jquery

I can't seem to get my button to work. the button will update mysql values when it is pressed. however, when i press the button, nothing happen. no logs appear on the console. did i miss something here?

the plan is to have a graph at the top and a table just below the graph. the graph will serve as a live graph. 
the value in the table will toggle between on/off to simulate control of a water pump.

**index2_2.php**

```
<?php
    require 'mysql.php';
?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
     <!-- jQuery Script -->
     <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script>
            // jQuery code
            // jQuery code available after the page has fully loaded
            $(".table #tbody1").on('click', ':button', function(){
                    id = $(this).prop("id");
                    console.log('button ' + id + ' pressed');

                    if($(this).prop('value') == 'ON'){
                        status = 'OFF';
                    }else{
                        status = 'ON';
                    }

                    // load table with updated values
                    $('#tbody1').load("mysql.php", {
                        id: id,
                        status: status
                    }, function(){
                        console.log('table loaded');
                    });
                });  
    </script>

     <script>
     window.onload = function() {      
     var updateInterval = 2000;
     var sensor1Data = [];
     var sensor2Data = [];

     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
         zoomEnabled: true,
         title: {
             text: "Soil Moisture Reading"
         },
         axisX: {
             title: "chart updates every " + updateInterval / 1000 + " secs"
         },
         axisY:{
             includeZero: false
         }, 
         toolTip: {
             shared: true
         },
         legend: {
             cursor:"pointer",
             verticalAlign: "top",
             fontSize: 22,
             fontColor: "dimGrey",
             itemclick : toggleDataSeries
         },
         data: [{ 
                 type: "line",
                 name: "Sensor 1",
                 dataPoints: sensor1Data
             },
             {
                 type: "line",
                 name: "Sensor 2",
                 dataPoints: sensor2Data
             }]
     });

     setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

     function toggleDataSeries(e) {
         if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
             e.dataSeries.visible = false;
         }
         else {
             e.dataSeries.visible = true;
         }
         chart.render();
     }

     function updateChart() {
        $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.3/Socket-4/getsensor.php", addData);
     }

     function addData(data){
         // try using ID to filter new values.
         // eg: newData[i].ID != oldData[i].ID
         // only plot new data. shift graph when datapoints > than a value
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i].sensorName == 'sensor 1'){
                sensor1Data.push({
                    x: new Date(data[i].Date), 
                    y: Number(data[i].sensorValue)
                });
            }

            if(data[i].sensorName == 'sensor 2'){
                sensor2Data.push({
                    x: new Date(data[i].Date), 
                    y: Number(data[i].sensorValue)
                });
            }
        }
        chart.render();
    }

    $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.3/Socket-4/getsensor.php", addData);

    }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
     <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

     <div class="table">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID:</th>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <th>Status:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='tbody1'>
                <?php
                    getValues();
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

**mysql.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'mysqldb.php';
    include 'socket.php';

    if(isset($_POST['id']) and isset($_POST['status'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        updateValues($id, $status);
        getValues();
    }

    function getValues(){
        /*
        This function retrieves the values from the database
        and store it in an array.
        */
        global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;
        $data = array();

        /* start connection */
        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM actuator ORDER BY ID';
        if($query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $data[] = $row;

                // Display into html table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$row['ID']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
                echo "<td>
                        <input type='button' id='{$row['ID']}' value='{$row['value']}' name='{$row['name']}'>
                    </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($query);
        }

        /* close connection */
        mysqli_close($conn);

        socket($data);
    }

    function updateValues($id, $status){
        /*
        This function updates the database with 
        values retrieved from POST.
        */

        global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;

        /* start connection */
        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
           printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
           exit();
        }

        // Prevent SQL injection
        $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $status);
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $id);

        // $sql = "UPDATE actuator SET value='$status' WHERE ID=$id";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO led_control (ID, value, name) VALUES ('$id', '$status', 'water pump')";

        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        /* close connection */
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I can't see any button in tbody bro ?

Comment: Why does selector have a colon? `':button'`

Comment: @KhalidKhan `<input type='button' ...` in `mysql.php`

Comment: @MarkusZeller jquery stuff https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Comment: Given that you're not seeing any console logs, it seems like the event handler isn't being added. Since the script tag that sets the onclick handler targets elements in the DOM, it would be best to put it at the very end of the body to ensure that the elements exist by the time jQuery goes looking for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the event handler

```
$(".table #tbody1").on('click', ':button', function(){
```

is called before the button is rendered.

Put the Handler inside of

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

like

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
            // jQuery code
            // jQuery code available after the page has fully loaded
            $(".table #tbody1").on('click', ':button', function(){
                    id = $(this).prop("id");
                    console.log('button ' + id + ' pressed');

                    if($(this).prop('value') == 'ON'){
                        status = 'OFF';
                    }else{
                        status = 'ON';
                    }

                    // load table with updated values
                    $('#tbody1').load("mysql.php", {
                        id: id,
                        status: status
                    }, function(){
                        console.log('table loaded');
                    });
                });  
});
    </script>
```

Comment: but the table doesn't update. the value in the database gets updated but the table doesn't 'reload'. i wonder why? could my mysql.php be the problem? i have tried adding getValues(); at the end of updateValues() but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can change echo like

```
echo "<td>
         <input type='button' id='{$row['ID']}' value='{$row['value']}' name='{$row['name']}' onClick=test({$row['ID']})>
       </td>";
```

and script:

```
function test(index){
   ....
}
```

or

```
echo "<td>
         <input class = 'nameofclass' type='button' id='{$row['ID']}' value='{$row['value']}' name='{$row['name']}' onClick=test({$row['ID']})>
       </td>";

$('table#tbody1').on('click','button.nameofclass',function(e) {
```

Comment: for your 2nd suggestion, is the onClick=test({$row['ID']}) still necessary?